# How to change the border color of a flat button style

Tags: wpf, button, coding-style, border

I'm trying to make a flat button with a red border instead of a black border when the button is pressed.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="FlatButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E01919"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The problem is that there still is a black border, so now its showing both a red and black border.

How do i get rid of the black border ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Stick this in your XAML `BorderBrush="#000000"` you can also grab a list of colours [here](http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/html2.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Flat">
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Flat}">Hello</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Set the `BorderThickness` to 0